# How to use biginteger in Clojure?

Tags: clojure, fibonacci, integer-overflow

I am trying to calculate the 500th Fibonacci number in Clojure:

```
(defn fib-pair [[a b]] [b (+ a b)])
(nth (map first (iterate fib-pair [1 1])) 500)
ArithmeticException integer overflow  clojure.lang.Numbers.throwIntOverflow (Numbers.java:1388)
```

This program failed because the number is too big: integer overflow. How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The default integer type in Clojure is `long`. If you want to specify that an integer literal should be considered a `clojure.lang.BigInt` just add an `N` right after the number.

```
(defn fib-pair [[a b]] [b (+ a b)])
(nth (map first (iterate fib-pair [1N 1N])) 500)
;= 225591516161936330872512695036072072046011324913758190588638866418474627738686883405015987052796968498626N
```

You can actually get away with just specifying only one of the two initial values as a `BigInt` since:

```
(+ 1N 1)
;= 2N
(type (+ 1N 1))
;= clojure.lang.BigInt
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use [clojure.core/+'](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/+%27) instead of [clojure.core/+](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/+) in `fib-pair`

This will auto promote longs when needed.

```
(defn fib-pair [[a b]] [b (+' a b)])
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use type hints.

```
(defn fib-pair ^BigInteger [[^BigInteger a ^BigInteger b]] [b (+' a b)])

(nth (map first (iterate fib-pair [1 1])) 500)
```

See for more info 
http://dev.clojure.org/display/doc/Documentation+for+1.3+Numerics

Comment: The type hints here don't do anything. This is just the same as the earlier suggestion to use `+'`. For example, try replacing `500` with `5`, and you'll see what you get back is not a BigInteger at all!